Wrapping setTimeout in a promise
I have read all of the similar questions about this on this site and can't seem to figure out exactly how to make setTimeout work with promises/await for my use case. I am using discord.js v14 and have a slash command that adds a role for 30 minutes. The command works, but occasionally, the bot won't remove the role. I think this is because setTimeout is not promisified/awaited and therefore runs before the awaited "member.roles.add(role.id)." How do I make setTimeout await?
P.S. each global variable corresponds to a different command that adds the role for a different amount of time (pug1Timeout = 1 hour, etc.).
const {
  CommandInteraction,
  PermissionsBitField,
  PermissionFlagsBits,
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder,
  ActionRowBuilder,
  Client,
  SelectMenuBuilder,
  ApplicationCommandOptionType,
  ChannelType,
} = require("discord.js");

//the pug queue commands reset the role timer to whatever the last used pug command time is

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("pug30")
    .setDescription("Adds the user to the PUG Queue for 30 minutes."),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const user = interaction.user.id;
    //is this supposed to be interaction.user?
    const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("628292255785943065");
    const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(user);

    if (!member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
      member.roles.add(role.id);

      global.pug30Timeout = setTimeout(
        () => member.roles.remove(role.id),
        1800000,
      );

      //await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1800000))

      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(" ")
        .setDescription(
          `Added ${interaction.user} to the PUG Queue for 30 minutes.`,
        )
        .setColor(0x4169e1);
      await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: false });
    } else {
      clearTimeout(global.pug30Timeout);
      clearTimeout(global.pug1Timeout);
      clearTimeout(global.pug2Timeout);
      clearTimeout(global.pug3Timeout);
      clearTimeout(global.pug4Timeout);

      //if user has the role already and uses this command again, it resets the timer

      global.pug30Timeout = setTimeout(
        () => member.roles.remove(role.id),
        1800000,
      );

      //need to repeat global.pug1Timeout = ... here because if you use this command more than 2 times before the time runs out it only resets to the 2nd timer

      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(" ")
        .setDescription(
          `Added ${interaction.user} to the PUG Queue for 30 minutes.`,
        )
        .setColor(0x4169e1);
      await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: false });
    }
  },
};


await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1800000)) looks like you know what you want ... if you want to "pause" for 30 minutes

Does this answer your question? How to make a promise from setTimeout

This sounds a lot like an XY Problem. I'd say your real problem is using the same global timer store (ie global.pug30Timeout) for all interactions. I would assume you'd need a separate timer per user and role

@JaromandaX How do I actually use that line with member.roles.remove(role.id) though? I can't just say resolve(member.roles.remove(role.id));
Also where would I include that line in the code?

Oh, sorry. I thought you didn't know how to use a setTimeout in a Promise to await for a delay - the specifics you just mentioned in your comment are meaningless to me

@Phil the global timers actually work fine because the constants defined are user-specific. I understand promises, but don't quite get the syntax of using a method like member.role.remove() with the promised version of setTimeout. Where do I put that method and where do I put the promisified line in my slash command? await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1800000))

"the constants defined are user-specific"... I don't see how that's possible. Only one instance of your app will be running therefore there's only one instance of global.pug30Timeout

This looks like a race condition due to shared use of global.pug30Timeout. Think about this process flow...

User #1 runs your slash command, the role is added and the timer started to remove it.
User #2 runs your command, the role is added and global.pug30Timeout now refers to User #2's removal timer. Both timers are still running though.
Then User #1 runs the command again. Now User #2's timer is cleared and global.pug30Timeout refers to User #1's new removal timer; User #2's role is never removed after this.

Store the timers in a map keyed by user to keep them isolated.
const removalTimers = new Map();

module.exports = {
  // ...

  async execute(interaction) {
    const user = interaction.user.id;
    const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('628292255785943065');
    const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(user);

    if (!member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
      member.roles.add(role.id);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(removalTimers.get(user));
    }

    removalTimers.set(
      user,
      setTimeout(() => {
        member.roles.remove(role.id);
      }, 1800000),
    );

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle(' ')
      .setDescription(
        `Added ${interaction.user} to the PUG Queue for 30 minutes.`,
      )
      .setColor(0x4169e1);
    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: false });
  },
};


That's not what's happening though. Not sure how familiar with discord.js you are, but the timeouts are user-specific because user is defined based on the interaction which is automatically user-specific. This command works fine 95% of the time with 10+ people using it. The only time it doesn't work is when the lines are executed out of order.
